# SharePoint 2019 Production farm started having struggle load Font File/Random PNG File/Random API call

Tags: performance, api, network

We have a SharePoint Farm (7 WFEs and 1 DB), last code deployment was weeks ago. Since Friday, when we load the web portal that is hosted on the farm via browser and via any location (worldwide), randomly, it takes 12-15 seconds to load one of the following:

1. The noto sans font file
2. One random PNG out of over 20 that we have in the home page
3. The bundle.js file that contains all the javascript of the page
4. An API call to a SharePoint list to get some items
5. An API call to an Azure cloud that we are pulling some data from

We have checked all the Servers, their Disk sizes, their CPU usages, their Memory usages, they all look healthy and fine, no spikes, no overutilization. We have checked with the Network team and they claim nothing was changed network wise. We have restarted IIS and the whole Farm.

Is there something that we can check from a SharePoint perspective, that might help us understand what is the root cause?

Comment: Hi Tasos, you did not explicitly mention the database servers. Have you checked them as well?

Comment: And you might check the developer dashboard https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/use-developer-dashboard or even enable trace logging in IIS.

Comment: Hi @ben yes we checked them, the disks have normal usage, we have a disk called TLog and it that stores the DB logs and for our main DB (which stores all the content), the log is 111GB

Comment: @ben I'm hitting CTRL-F12 for developer dashboard but it does not pop up. I don't know if it is because we use SharePoint Server 2019

Comment: Have you installed any SharePoint updates recently? Have you taken a look at the IIS logs?

Comment: @ben no updates installed recently. In the IIS logs, we just see web requests coming through and their response status code

Comment: @Tasos. I did not mean the F12 tools, but the SharePoint developer dashboard as described in my link.